# Can SublimeGit be configured to ignore white space changes?

Tags: git, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Apparently SublimeGit has a settings file to change a number of git options. Ignoring white space changes when doing a diff seems not one of them. I also don't find a solution on the web. Somebody any ideas?

Comment: Ignore whitespace *when*? For diffs? Or when adding files?

Comment: When executing a diff...

Comment: Considering that SublimeGit is a *paid* extension, you should probably contact their support for help.

Comment: There is an [open feature request for this](https://github.com/SublimeGit/SublimeGit/issues/17), meaning it is not yet implemented yet

Comment: @KeithHall you should make that an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [open feature request for this](https://github.com/SublimeGit/SublimeGit/issues/17), meaning that it is not yet implemented and thus not yet possible with this plugin.